# Recursively find directories by a specific name and then clear them

Tags: linux, bash, find

Suppose that the following project structure is given:

```
/
|
|- /bin
|- /src
     |
     |- /bin
     |- abc
         ...
         |
         |- /bin
```

and I would like to erase the contents of the `bin` subdirectories, but not delete them. How do I achieve tis through the Bash command line?

**EDIT**

I have tried `find . -regex bin/* -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;`, but to no avail.

Comment: If you are deleting the contents of `bin` wouldn't the entire tree below the top `bin` be removed?

Comment: Sorry if the depiction is not clear. I did not intend to suggest that anything in the above depiction is under a `bin` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest with GNU find:

```
find . -regex ".*/bin/.*" -type f -exec echo rm {} \;
```

if everything looks fine remove `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to delete files, it is unnecessary (indeed dangerous) to pass `-r` to `rm`.

Besides, `find` "knows" how to delete, without the need to call `rm` in the first place.

```
find . -type f -wholename "*/bin/*" -delete
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Debug your command: try each argument to `find` in isolation to see if it is producing expected output.

We quickly see that

```
find . -regex bin/*
```

doesn't work because of an issue in regex. If we check the [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) for find, we see that the regex must match the full path:

> -regex pattern
>        File name matches regular expression pattern.  This is a match
>        on the whole path, not a search.  For example, to match a file
>        named `./fubar3', you can use the regular expression`.*bar.'
>        or `.*b.*3', but not`f.*r3'.

This should do the job:

```
find . -regex '".*/bin/.*"' -type d -delete
```

or using your command:

```
find . -regex '".*/bin/.*"' -type d -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Remember to quote your expressions to avoid unexpected shell expansion.

Comment: This would delete the `bin` directory, which is precisely what I do not want. I want to only delete the contents of the `bin` directories.

Comment: @progfan Ah missed that- but no matter the answer still applies. Your regex was incorrect (not matching the path) and you just need to adjust it to do so. In your case you want ".*/bin/.*". Edited my answer